# ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND vs ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, what is the difference?

Tags: c++, winapi, windowserror

I usually get `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` when I try to open a file that's not there, but now `fopen()` fails and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.

So what is the difference between `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `WinError.h`, `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` has the descriptive text "The system cannot find the file specified." and `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` has the descriptive text "The system cannot find the path specified."

This doesn't particularly clarify matters.

Usually, however, "file not found" refers to the case where the file itself cannot be found and "path not found" refers to the case where a component of the path (one of the directory names specified) cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was because I was %appdata% inside the path. It seems fopen doesn't accept envvars.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the canonical meaning could be deduced from the names of the error codes.

The *specific* meaning, as it is with all "generic" error codes, highly depends on the implementation of the function that is said to "produce" this error. For an even worse example in this respect, consider the error `ERROR_INVALID_DATA` - only the documentation of the function could tell what should be ment by it.

This brings us to the point that `fopen` does not even ([officially](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) return or set those error codes. `fopen` is part of the CRT library and is thus documented to use the error reporting mechanism thereof: `errno`.

Looking at the implementation of `fopen` in the CRT source code, you can see (ultimately, it is quite a callstack of internal helper functions), that `fopen` in the end calls (not surprisingly) the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API. It then carefully maps the errors potentially returned by `CreateFile` to errno-like errors (using the internal `_dosmaperr()` function, if you still want to follow in the CRT sources). This maps both `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` to the errno `ENOENT`.

So in the context of `fopen` the distinction is best considered meaningless as it is an implementation detail of `fopen`.

Comment: +1 for featuring the relation between fopen and CreateFile

Answer (score 3):

`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` means, that the container directory does not exist.
`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` means, the container directory exists, and it does not contain the named file.